# age range for date of birth

Tags: php, mysql

Good day guys. i have here my code its in mysql format eventhough i know it's depreciated, so i'm only focusing on how to get total number of my data in database via age range.

my table structure for outputting

```
age range |Male |Female | Total
   0-4    |     |       |
   5-9    |     |       |
  so on.. |     |       |
  total   |     |       |
```

my code

```
//for 0-4 age range
SELECT count(*) as total FROM data WHERE gender='male' and dob BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 YEAR AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 0 YEAR";
//for 5-9 age range
SELECT count(*) as total FROM data WHERE gender='male' and dob BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 9 YEAR AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 YEAR";
```

i manage to get all the total in every age range of both male and female but when i count it manually it is not **exact** from the total row below. Please
 help me out of this problem, im just a newbie in php and mysql so i'm going to learn more . thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"when i count it manually it is not exact from the total row below"*. Can you clarify?

Comment: the total number of my data in database is not equal when i sum up manually the total number when i categorise it in age range column. i sum up all the numbers in age range (male) column and check it in the total number of males in not the same. i hope you get my explanation. @MarkM thankyou for your reply. :)